# Exporting a list of genes to .csv after carrying out sc.tl.rank_genes_groups in scanpy

Tags: python, output, scanpy

I am relatively new to Python and Scanpy and recently i have generated a list of differentially expressed genes by using the

`sc.tl.rank_genes_groups`

function in scanpy.. I can then get these genes to be listed in the console, by carrying out this command set

```
    result = adata_subset.uns['rank_genes_groups']
`   groups = result['names'].dtype.names
    pd.DataFrame(
    {group + '_' + key[:1]: result[key][group]
    for group in groups for key in ['names','logfoldchanges','pvals','pvals_adj']})'
```

However, i want this to be accessible via a csv file, as this list doesnt show all the genes...
Any help would be much appreciated!
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like to use the dictionary comprehension there is also the function `sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df` which makes your life easier. Quick example:

```
sc.tl.rank_genes_groups(adata, group, key_added = "extract_later")
df = sc.get.rank_genes_groups_df(adata, group, key = "extract_later")
df.to_csv("filepath.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've created the dataframe, you simply need to use the to_csv function:

```
result = adata_subset.uns['rank_genes_groups']
groups = result['names'].dtype.names
df = pd.DataFrame(
{group + '_' + key[:1]: result[key][group]
for group in groups for key in ['names','logfoldchanges','pvals','pvals_adj']})
df.to_csv('path/to/file.csv')
```